# android studio user interface design tutorial out of date

Tags: android, interface

At developer.android.com I found a tutorial called "Build a simple user interface".  Unfortunately, it is based on an older version of Android Studio.  It tells the user to open activity_main.xml.  If one does this, the user cannot find the right icons in the toolbar.  I searched and someone said open content_main.xml instead.  This indeed posts the right icons in the toolbar, but as one continues in the tutorial, more and more errors appear. My question is: Is there a newer Android Studio User Interface tutorial that is appropriate for the latest Android Studio, version 3.6.1?

I really want to learn how to build interfaces via Android Studio and not clumsily play directly with XML code.  Thanks for any ideas!

--Steve

Comment: I assume you mean [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui). I suggest that you post feedback directly on that page. There is a "Was this content useful" widget on the bottom. Give it one star and provide any other feedback you can when it asks.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of activity_main.xml? Also please provide the Support Library  you are using : AndroidX or Appcompact?

Comment: Thanks Code-Apprentice.  Good idea - will do.  Actually, the link you mention is for Guides: Core Topics->User interface->Overview while I was looking at Guides: Build your first app->Build a simple user interface, but point taken.

Comment: Thanks Sanjan for your input -- let me check that information...

Comment: Sanjan -- I started a new activity, this time, using "Empty Activity" instead of "Basic Activity" and it has in MainActivity.java this:import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;  This is activity_main.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" ... Ran out of space for the rest